# Can I play gog's OSX version of SWOS two players both on the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, swos

I've just bought [SWOS](http://www.gog.com/game/sensible_world_of_soccer_9697) from gog and downloaded it for OSX, tried to play it with a friend, but the arrow keys controlled both teams, and couldn't find any other key controlling only one team and not the other one.

Is there a way to fix that, or are joypads required?

Comment: One thing to note: Even if it's possible to control both teams with a single keyboard, you might run into issues with your keyboard's anti-ghosting system. In other words: as soon as too many keys are pressed, your keyboard may refuse any additional inputs. So you'll need a relatively high-end keyboard for this to work, and those are usually very expensive.